# Prove the relation $\sim$ on $M\times T$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1$ and $T$ a non-empty multiplicatively closed subset of $R$, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Define a relation $\sim$ on $M\times T$ as follows: $(m, t)\sim (m', t') \iff \exists s \in T \text{ such that } stm' = st'm.$

Prove the relation $\sim$ on $M\times T$ is an equivalence relation.

(1) Reflexive

$(m, t)\sim (m, t) \iff \exists s \in T \text{ such that } stm = stm.$ (it is clear)

(2) Symmetric

$(m, t)\sim (m', t') \iff \exists s \in T \text{ such that } stm' = st'm.$ We  can see that $(m', t')\sim (m, t)$, i.e. $\exists s \in T \text{ such that } st'm = stm'.$ (it is clear)

(3) Transitive

$(m, t)\sim (m', t')$ and $(m', t')\sim (m'', t'')$ mean 
$$
\exists s_1 \in T \text{ such that } s_1tm' = s_1t'm
$$
and
$$
\exists s_2 \in T \text{ such that } s_2t'm'' = s_2t''m'.
$$
We must prove there exist $s_3\in T$ such that $s_3tm'' = s_3t''m$. How to obtain that?

Comment: Your statement for $2$ is incorrect. In particular, $(t,m)$ doesn't even lie in $M \times T$.

Comment: Your statement for $3$ is incorrect. Note that $t^"$ and $m^"$ do not even figure in your definition.

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Is statement for 2 correct?

How to prove (3)?

Comment: Statement (2) is correct; for (3), I am stuck myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling that we're in a commutative setting, let's equalize the $s_1tm^\prime$ and $s_2t^{\prime\prime}m^\prime$ term by multiplying the first equation by $s_2t^{\prime\prime}$ and the second by $s_1t$.  This gives us
\begin{align}
  s_2t^{\prime\prime} \cdot s_1tm^\prime &= s_2t^{\prime\prime} \cdot s_1t^\prime m \\
  s_1t \cdot s_2t^\prime m^{\prime\prime} &= s_1t \cdot s_2t^{\prime\prime}m^\prime
\end{align}
Rearranging, we get $s_1s_2t^\prime t^{\prime\prime}m = s_1s_2tt^{\prime\prime} m^\prime = s_1s_2t^\prime t m^{\prime\prime}$.  Because $T$ is multiplicatively closed, $s_1s_2t^\prime$ is still in $T$, giving us the desired mediator between $t^{\prime\prime}m$ and $tm^{\prime\prime}$.